# How to change the colour of embedded terminal in linux mint 12 to be able to use `ls` and `byobu`?

Tags: terminal, ls, linux-mint, gedit, byobu

I'm using Linux Mint 12 and am having problems with the embedded terminal in gedit.

Using the default themes I'm unable to use 'ls' and 'byobu' as in part of their output foreground and background colours are the same.

Problems shown in this screenshot. Byobu is running (bottom two lines of terminal) and ls has just been used.

[image]

I've followed the instructions in https://askubuntu.com/questions/67593/make-gedit-embedded-terminal-colours-the-same-as-the-default-terminal but have had no luck with that.

Any ideas would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you're experiencing this, you will need to edit `/usr/share/byobu/profiles/common` and comment out these two lines:

```
attrcolor b ".I"                                          
termcapinfo xterm 'Co#256:AB=\E[48;5;%dm:AF=\E[38;5;%dm'
```

I've not yet figured out what combination of terminals experience this problem, but there is an open bug, and rest assured I'm working on it ;-)

Comment: Cheers for that! - I've moved to Ubuntu 11.10 using byobu within gedit and experience the same problem. That has currently fixed it but perhaps after a restart of the apps, I'll let you know

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps, I can't test it. From the 'ls' man page:

> -G      Enable colorized output.  This option is equivalent to defining
>                CLICOLOR in the environment.  (See below.)
>
> CLICOLOR        Use ANSI color sequences to distinguish file types. 
>   See
>                        LSCOLORS below.  In addition to the file types mentioned
>                        in the -F option some extra attributes (setuid bit set,
>                        etc.) are also displayed.  The colorization is dependent
>                        on a terminal type with the proper termcap(5) capabili-
>                        ties.  The default `cons25'' console has the proper
>                        capabilities, but to display the colors in an xterm(1),
>                        for example, the TERM variable must be set to`
>   xterm-color''.  Other terminal types may require simi-
>                        lar adjustments.  Colorization is silently disabled if
>                        the output isn't directed to a terminal unless the
>                        CLICOLOR_FORCE variable is defined.
>
> CLICOLOR_FORCE  Color sequences are normally disabled if the output isn't
>                        directed to a terminal.  This can be overridden by set-
>                        ting this flag.  The TERM variable still needs to refer-
>                        ence a color capable terminal however otherwise it is not
>                        possible to determine which color sequences to use.